# Traversal of EdgeReversedGraph

Tags: jgrapht

I created a SimpleDirectedGraph and traversed it using a BreadthFirstIterator.  Then I created an EdgeReversedGraph of the first graph and traversed that.  I was expected the output to be inverted but it's basically the same.

The code is:

public class TestJGraphT {

```
private static Graph<String, DefaultEdge> createStringGraph() {
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> g = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);

    String v1 = "v1";
    String v2 = "v2";
    String v3 = "v3";
    String v4 = "v4";
    String v5 = "v5";
    String v6 = "v6";
    String v7 = "v7";

    // add the vertices
    g.addVertex(v1);
    g.addVertex(v2);
    g.addVertex(v3);
    g.addVertex(v4);
    g.addVertex(v5);
    g.addVertex(v6);
    g.addVertex(v7);
    
    // add edges
    g.addEdge(v1, v2);
    g.addEdge(v1, v3);
    g.addEdge(v3, v4);
    g.addEdge(v4, v5);
    g.addEdge(v5, v7);
    g.addEdge(v3, v6);
    g.addEdge(v6, v7);
    
    return g;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> stringGraph = createStringGraph();
    BreadthFirstIterator<String, DefaultEdge> iterator = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(stringGraph);
    
    System.out.println("\n\n\nGraph BreadthFirst\n");
    
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String node = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(node);
    }
    
    
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> stringGraphReversed = new EdgeReversedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(stringGraph);
    BreadthFirstIterator<String, DefaultEdge> iteratorReversed = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(stringGraphReversed);
    
    System.out.println("\n\n\nReversed Graph BreadthFirst\n");
    
    while (iteratorReversed.hasNext()) {
        String node = iteratorReversed.next();
        System.out.println(node);
    }
    
}
```

}

The output is:

Graph BreadthFirst

v1
v2
v3
v4
v6
v5
v7

Reversed Graph BreadthFirst

v1
v2
v3
v4
v5
v6
v7

I was expecting the EdgeReversedGraph to print v7, v6, v5 ...

How do I visit the nodes in the first graph depth first where v7 is considered the "deepest" node?

Answer (score 0):

I see.  I need to pass the starting node to the iterator:

BreadthFirstIterator<String, DefaultEdge> iteratorRev = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(stringGraphReversed, "v7");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).